# How do you feed a winform after clicking on a row of a datagridview of search form?

Tags: .net, winforms, search, send

I have a winform which is responsible for doing a search by some conditions that users enters and then selects the records from a Database.
The search form has a data grid view which shows the result.
After searching, user clikcs on a row of the datagridview and then another form (for example frmShowDetails) will be displayed.

My question is when displaying frmShowDetails, what are your suggestions to send the id of selected row to frmShowDetails in order to feed it to show data in .net? Do you use form property or a private variable which sets by only form constructor?

Answer (score 1):

By sending the id of the DataRow as a parameter you will have to make another call to DB to get the details. Instead create a Type that holds the data which would be displayed in the ShowDetailsForm. And before showing the Form populate the Type with data and pass it on to the ShowDetailsForm ctor.

```
ProductDetails productDetails = new ProductDetails { Name = "ProductA" };
ShowDetailsForm showDetailsForm = new ShowDetailsForm(productDetails);
showDetailsForm.ShowDialog(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass parameter in a constructor to frmShowDetails.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use form properties. Have a feeling, that passing data through ctor is not a very good decision, but I might be wrong.